# PyQt5 5.8.2 QLineEdit has no attribute 'setPlaceHolderText'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qlineedit, qtwidgets

I'm trying figure out whats wrong with my PyQt5 install, I've looked at all the documentation and I should be able to use `placeHolderText` and `setPlaceHolderText()` but it doesn't look like it does. The `QtWidgets.QLineEdit()` works and shows up on my gui but can get it to `setPlaceHolderText`. Also `QLayout.setFixedSize` also returns the same error. Importing PyQt5 doesn't return any errors so these should work too.

I installed PyQt5 through pip3 on python 3.5.2, has anyone had this issue before, I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: The 'h' is lowercase in [`setPlaceholderText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop).

Comment: I just realized that myself sorry for bothering you stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

so umm... sightly embarrassing, 
`setPlaceHolderText()` is suppose to have a lowercase `h -> setPlaceholderText()`
and `QLayout.setFixedSize` is suppose to have uppercase `S -> SetFixedSize()`